# accessing template variables within template Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, handlebars.js

My client script uses this example code

```
function initValue(data){
  myValue = data;
}

var myValue;
```

And from the server I render the template with

```
app.get('main/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('main', {
      myValue: Number(req.params.id)
     });
  });
```

The template itself got a reference to Jquery and the client script. I want to set the variable `myValue` when loading the page, so in my template file at the top I have this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = {{myValue}};
initValue(data);
});
</script>
```

When assigning the variable `data` I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How can I access the template variable?

Comment: What do you see for it's value in the generated browser source?

Comment: `console.log([object Object]);`